# Follow feature : My site needed or no?

Tags: 2013

Is it mandatory to have mysites when you want to use follow feature for document libraries ? I just want follow feature , so dont see a need to have have mysite created for 300,000 users because i would then need to plan for the mysite architecture which would be huge invest .

Answer (score 2):

The follow function needs the MySite Site Collection. The information is stored in the site collection. There is a special List named Social in every MySite storing this information.

For the Followed Document are store under the url:  `https://mysite.host/personal/<name>/Social/Followed Document`

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like this feature is required for the Follow Documents.

I am sure you dont need the Mysite, but you need the User Profile Service. All the social stuff stored in User's profile not in the MySite.

It is development link but good to read it.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163217.aspx

Comment: Yes but how does user follow a document ? He would then need mysite right .

Comment: you thinking, if a user follow a document then it will store on user's my site...i dont think that is true, My understanding is all the follows / scoial feature stores into social db of UPA( aka store into user's profile).

Comment: I created a web app and new site collection and tried to follow a document . It gave me pop saying "User needs a personal site" . So i would definately need someone to follow a doc , so i can retrieve the followed doc.

Comment: ok then that's it. I havent tried that. But good to know.